# Slow first load for each browser or after a while

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

I have a low-traffic ASP.NET MVC 4 application that run on Windows Server 2008 / IIS 7.5.
My problem is that:

- The **first request is slow** around 15 sec. (Subsequent requests are fine)
- **Another request after about 2 minutes** without any requests always gets a slow response (around 15 sec)
- After first request if I make **another request from new browser**, again it takes 15 sec.

A scenario to address the problem (the document size is 24 KB):

1. Time: 16:26 - Using Chrome - First Request takes 15 sec. Subsequent requests are fine.
2. Time: 16:27 - Using Firefox - First Request takes 15 sec. Subsequent requests are fine.
3. Time: 16:30 - Using IE 11 - First Request takes 15 sec. Subsequent requests are fine.

[Here is all screenshots of Developer Tools/Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7d73.png)

And also Fiddler time output:

```
Request Count:  1
Bytes Sent:     380     (headers:380; body:0)
Bytes Received: 7,217       (headers:409; body:6,808)

ACTUAL PERFORMANCE
--------------
ClientConnected:    22:41:26.377
ClientBeginRequest: 22:41:26.378
GotRequestHeaders:  22:41:26.378
ClientDoneRequest:  22:41:26.378
Determine Gateway:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect: 28ms
HTTPS Handshake:    0ms
ServerConnected:    22:41:26.407
FiddlerBeginRequest:    22:41:26.407
ServerGotRequest:   22:41:26.407
ServerBeginResponse:    22:41:41.496
GotResponseHeaders: 22:41:41.496
ServerDoneResponse: 22:41:41.503
ClientBeginResponse:    22:41:41.503
ClientDoneResponse: 22:41:41.504

Overall Elapsed:    00:00:15.1258651
```

It shows 15 sec delay between **ServerGotRequest** and **ServerBeginResponse**

This issue just occurs at my home. There is no problem at work or my friends computers (means another ISP). Also I have no problem in internet speed, then I tested my website connection:

output for `ping neshoonak.ir`

```
Reply from 94.232.172.248: bytes=32 time=67ms TTL=122
Reply from 94.232.172.248: bytes=32 time=56ms TTL=122
Reply from 94.232.172.248: bytes=32 time=63ms TTL=122
```

output for `ping 8.8.8.8`

```
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=134ms TTL=47
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=171ms TTL=47
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=132ms TTL=47
```

I tested some sites placed in same data-center that my site located 
and found that all of them have the same problem (there is no problem at work at all).

My reseller hosting says there is 3 data-center and I have problem with 2 of them (just at home). He proposed to move my website to the third data-center. But it may occurs for my site visitors and I don't want to solve it just for me.

Please help!

Comment: It could be a bandwidth issue, which is higher at your work place as compared to your home DSL. Also, your pages might be getting multiple (i.e. many) CSS and JavaScript files resulting in multiple network trips. Try to minimize the JavaSript and CSS files, and also combine them if possible to minimize number of trips. More trips means more time for page to render.

Comment: Also, view your website Network stats in Google Chrome Developer tool ( there is a time tab that exactly tells how much wait time and download time it took). This will probably tell you what is the source of slow response.

Comment: Also, do you have a lot of `inline` JavaScript and CSS in your pages? If yes, then that can also cause bad performance.

Comment: Thanks Sunil for your reply, it's not about bandwidth subsequent requests are fantastic. It's happens for a single static html.
 I measured the 15 sec using developer tools in Chrome, IE, FF. 
 totally I'm sure it's not about app layer. It seems there is a long delay between my browser at home and web server.

Comment: Did you look at the Network tab in Chrome Dev Tools and notice which resource took a long time? May be a resource is taking a long time to initially load, and after that it's cached and so requests after first one are fast. Now if you change browser, again the first request is going to be slow since it does not have a cached version of the expensive resource.

Comment: I added my screenshot of IE 11 developer tools. It shows that web request of takes 15 sec. 
I realized all of websites in my data-center has this problem. ISP says there is no problem in my internet. I don't know what should I do.

Comment: Are you running some large query in that page? Queries against databases can take a longer time when first executed. Also, it could be a problem with your ISP, though that should not happen.

Comment: This old problem was solved after a few weeks. I guess it was related to my shared host. But they never gave me an explanation and I did not understand how the problem was solved. Also thanks to @xmorera, for his comments on that days. I think it is better to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilies that come to mind:

1. Caching: there are some resources that are not cached and thus they need to be loaded and that takes a while. How do you identify if this is the case? Install Fiddler and open the page. You will see the http response codes. How to fix? Cache :)
2. App pool: does not seem to be your issue but want to mention for other readers. This happened to me in an app for a Microsoft portal. They wanted near instant loading and it worked fine... Sometimes. I debugged and profiled the code a few times until it hit me. The problem was that the app pool was recycled and it needed to start and load everything. How did I fix? I set up a cron job every 5 minutes to open one page and this kept the app loaded in memory this getting near instant responses.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have no problem in caching. I used Fiddler and found a long delay during send request to the server, but response time has no problem
...
ServerConnected: 22:41:26.407
FiddlerBeginRequest: 22:41:26.407
ServerGotRequest: 22:41:26.407
ServerBeginResponse: 22:41:41.496
GotResponseHeaders: 22:41:41.496
ServerDoneResponse: 22:41:41.503
...

Comment: Can it be a dns resolution issue? Highly unlikely but can you try with IP or setting Google's 8.8.8.8. Worth giving a shot.

Comment: Here is part of "ping 8.8.8.8 -t" result:  
  Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=134ms TTL=47  
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=171ms TTL=47  
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=132ms TTL=47  
...   
I tested some sites placed in same data-center that my site located and found that all of them have the same problem (there is no problem at work). 
My reseller hosting says there is 3 data-center and I have problem with 2 of them (just at home). He proposed to move my website to the third data-center. But it may occurs for my site visitors and I don't want  to solve it just for me.

Answer (score 0):

One good test is to set up a monitoring service like www.site24x7.com and have it ping your site from multiple locations and you can see response time there.

Comment: I used the Test tool provided in this great site. As I expected response time is not bad. California - US : 1049 ms, Toronto - CA: 530 ms, Singapore - SG: 1787 ms, Chennai - IN: 1621, Melbourne - AUS: 1894. Today I called ISP again and seems it's just me that have this problem. Now I just suspect to my modem. but I don't know how!

Comment: I once used wireshark to troubleshoot a connection issue and it was very good, but had a steep learning curve

Comment: I installed the Wireshark and just for easy testing wrote a program to make request. [This is Wireshark result of 2 request](http://neshoonak.ir/_data/temp/Wireshark.png). it also shows that the first request has a 15 sec delay and second is fine.
My website logger says that session is started at about 22:05:08 (to reach to this time I created a method at /home/getdate and I did so many trys to find out diffrence between server & client time). Now a big question is how could I know what events/packets/requests reached to server in time between 22:04:54 until 22:05:08

Comment: It looks looks like the delay is in your modem or router as you suspected in the 192.168.1.x.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the problem turned out to be me having my proxy settings on...So the solution is: just go type proxy after pressing windows button (mine is windows 10) and make sure everything is turned off.